# ssh login to remote hosted server having cpanel

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, cpanel, whm

I have recently bought a cpanel account from a web host re-seller.

As far I know, cpanel is only the web interface to simplify the process of hosting a web site. Also, it provides command line access (which I am going to talk about) for remote login.

Since, this cpanel that has been provided from re-seller:

1. Is it possible to configure my web server remotely?
2. If yes? How can I do ssh login? (Any detail tutorial will be more helpful)
3. If no then do I need WHM account for this?

Thank

Comment: You can only use ssh if you have been provided that access.  Talk to your hosting provider about your options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPanel, the webserver/mysql server/mailserver is shared by multiple users. As a result, the webserver configuration is managed by CPanel and the configuration files cannot be changed directly by users. The creation/modification/management of subdomains/addon domains/parked domains are also managed by CPanel and manual configuration editing is not possible. The only user that can edit the webserver configuration directly is the system administrator who has root access to the CPanel server.

While some providers will provide SSH access to your account, the SSH access that comes with your account does not permit you to configure the webserver manually. The same thing applies to WHM accounts.

If you want to be able to configure your webserver manually, I suggest getting a VPS (Virtual Private Server) or a Dedicated Server.